# sed command with option -n and '$='

Tags: sed

I want to print number of lines in a file using the `sed` command. I have the following line for that, please can any one explain in detail.

```
sed -n '$=' myfile.txt
```

Comment: This question is badly tagged. It is in no way related to the linux kernel. Really, `sed` should be the only tag for a question so specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you get some command that works but you don't understand the options use `man command` to get more information about the options used. `man sed` will show you (if you scroll/search through the output):

```
   -n, --quiet, --silent

          suppress automatic printing of pattern space
```

and

```
   =      Print the current line number.
```

and (searching for `$` can be done by prefixing it with a backslash `\`):

```
   $      Match the last line.
```

So it gives you the line number of the last line, without additionally printing the matching line (the last line) found, which would be the default.

Answer (score 1):

`=` prints the current line number. `$` is the last line in the file. `-n` suppresses the usual output.

Comment: what does -n option